# "Correct" way to interact with numpy objects

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

I've been using scientific python (via `from pylab import *`) on and off for a while as a free Matlab substitute, mainly for work in chemical engineering (I'm a fan of the IPython Notebook). Something that's always appeared strange to me is the fact that there's generally two different ways to interact with an object. For instance, if I have an array, I can tell its dimensions in two ways:

`a = array([1,2,3],[2,3,4])`

There's the 'Matlab' way:

`shape(a)`

Or instead I could find it by typing:

`a.shape`

This seems to contradict The Zen of Python: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it"

I'm just wondering why there's multiple ways of doing the same thing, and which practice is more fundamental/natural for the language and would be better to use in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

Using the method is preferable.  After all, the implementation of `shape` simply defers to the method anyway (from `/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py`):

```
def shape(a):
    try:
        result = a.shape
    except AttributeError:
        result = asarray(a).shape
    return result
```

I assume a lot of this pylab stuff is just included to help ease the transition for people coming from MATLAB.  Get used to it because there are *many* more examples of numpy being, ahem, not very pythonic.

When you get more used to python and matplotlib you will likely want to ditch the `from pylab import *` anyway and start writing more numpythonic code, rather than MATLAB style work.

Answer (score 3):

It mostly comes down to a matter of preference, but there are a few differences that you might want to be aware of. First off, you should be using `numpy.shape(a)` or `np.shape(a)` instead of `shape(a)`, that's because "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!" But really, numpy has several names you'll likely find in other python modules, ie `array` appears as `array.array` in python stdlib, `numpy.array` and `numpy.ma.array`, so to avoid confusing other (and yourself) just go ahead and avoid import the entire numpy namespace.

Other than that, turns out that `numpy.shape`, and most other similar functions, just look for a shape attribute/method on the argument and if they don't find one, they try and convert the argument to an array. Here is the code:

```
def shape(a):
    try:
        result = a.shape
    except AttributeError:
        result = asarray(a).shape
    return result
```

This can be useful if you want the shape of an "array_like" object, you'll notice that most numpy functions take "array_like" arguments. But it can be slow if you're doing something like:

```
shape = np.shape(list_of_lists)
mx = np.max(list_of_lists)
mn = np.min(list_of_lists)
```

Other than that, they're pretty much the same.